# Is it possible to generalize a Voronoi diagram into a k-means cluster?

Tags: computational-geometry

In a *n*-dimensional Euclidean metric space, given a Voronoi decomposition for a set of *S* points (computed with Bowyer-Watson algorithm), is it possible to generalize *k* (with *k<S*) geometric clusters by converging multiple Dirichlet domains?

Comment: I sure hope you mean ***Voronoi*** diagram. If not, you'll have to explain to the uninformed masses what a Voropoi diagram really is.

Comment: YES!  You just use this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rLDgQg6bq7o

Comment: Sounds like a homework question. If so, please tag accordingly.

Comment: Sorry; it's not meant to be incomprehensible.

Comment: what does "generalizing k geometric clusters" mean? what does "converging multiple Dirichlet domains" mean?

Comment: @Wram, if it's not meant to be incomprehensible, why don't you clarify a bit, as asked by @balint.miklos?

Comment: Are you talking about order-k voronoi diagrams like these? http://www.personal.kent.edu/~rmuhamma/Compgeometry/MyCG/CG-Applets/VoroHiOrder/hivorocli.htm

Comment: Actually I figured it out yesterday. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @Wram, in case people find your question through a search engine, you might consider posting the answer yourself.